# Qt - This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: qt

I am using Qt 6.5.2

I have developed my app on MacOS and there it builds and runs no problems.
I've managed to build the program on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 however when I
try start it I get this error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: offscreen, linuxfb, vnc, wayland-egl, eglfs, xcb, minimalegl, wayland, vkkhrdisplay, minimal.
```

I have also done this:

```
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/Qt/6.5.2/gcc_64/plugins
```

But this pretty much changes nothing. Than I check this:

```
ls -l /opt/Qt/6.5.2/gcc_64/plugins
total 132
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 assetimporters
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:23 canbus
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:28 designer
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 egldeviceintegrations
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 generic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:25 geometryloaders
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 geoservices
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:20 iconengines
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 imageformats
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:18 multimedia
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 networkinformation
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:26 opcua
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 platforminputcontexts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 platforms
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 platformthemes
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:28 position
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 printsupport
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:27 qmllint
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:27 qmltooling
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:25 renderers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:25 renderplugins
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:25 sceneparsers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:29 scxmldatamodel
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:24 sensors
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 sqldrivers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 texttospeech
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 tls
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:25 wayland-decoration-client
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:25 wayland-graphics-integration-client
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:25 wayland-graphics-integration-server
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:25 wayland-shell-integration
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 webview
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 юли  8 04:19 xcbglintegrations
```

Which shows that there are plugins.

So why do I get this error and how can I fix it ?

P.S.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/hK2SEUVB) is the log after `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`

Comment: Execute: `sudo apt install libxcb-cursor0`